# Versioning DKNF attributes

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

I have a `person`table with two attributes, `eye_colour` and `hair_colour`. If I'm correct, if I want to normalize it to DKNF, I will need 2 attribute tables, `person_eye_colour` and `person_hair_colour`. Each table will have one column for the original `person_id` and one for the attribute's value.

However if I want to version the `hair_colour` attribute, I need it to be in two separate tables: one table (say `hair_colour_version`) would map the ids to values, while another table (eg. `hair_colour_value`) would map the same ids to values. In this case the `person_hair_colour` table would need the `hair_colour id` instead of the colour value.

Of course another choice is to not version the attribute value, but to version the relation between the person and the attribute eg. create separate `person_hair_colour_value` and `person_hair_colour_version` tables.

Question: given my assumptions above are correct, which choice of versioning makes more sense? Should the attribute be versioned or the relation between the attribute and its holder entity?

Comment: I'd expect your additional tables to be "eye_colors" and "hair_colors", containing all the valid values for eye color and for hair color, respectively.

Comment: Yes, the example is flawed as I chose attributes with finite value sets (thus the values can be the IDs).

Comment: I would say the example is flawed because your "attribute tables" contain a "person_id" attribute.

Comment: I'd like to see your idea on this.

Comment: Satisfy DKNF with single-column tables and foreign key references. Adding the tables `person_eye_color` and `person_hair_color` satisfies 6NF. Version with timestamps. (A timestamp is a non-prime attribute, but it doesn't violate DKNF.)

Comment: Specifically: `eye_colour = 'blue' and hair_colour='red'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing (Fagin's) DKNF and (Date's) 6NF. If you are versioning, you probably want 6NF, which says a table isn't always the join of smaller ones. DKNF means the only constraints on a table arise from its column types and its keys. In particular, if a source table has a FK to a destination table, the source table by definition isn't in DKNF. DKNF has nothing to do with versioning per se and isn't part of normalization through 5NF and 6NF.

The wiki for '6NF' says some call DKNF 6NF, so maybe that's confusing you. But no one calls 6NF DKNF. Except the wiki for 'Domain/key normal form', which also contains other nonsense. So go somewhere else for your versioning info.

Anyway, your example seems to involve attributes for person_id and version, but you are not clear. Explain the tables of your options in full.